# Read file located up to index.html

Tags: javascript

I am new in JavaScript.

My index.html uses JavaScript to read file. If the file located in the same directory with index.html or relative to it I can read it successfully. But when the file located up to index.html (../../myfile) JavaScript cannot access it. 
Is that possible to read the file with standard JavaScript?

Comment: What kind of file are we talking about?

Comment: It is .json log file

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this could help read local files:

```
function readFile(data, elem, file, index) {
     if (!file)
         return;
     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onloadend = readFileLoadEnd(data, elem, file, index);
     reader.readAsDataURL(file);
 }
```